# European soil texture dataset according to USDA classification

Tags: soil, geospatial

I'm looking for a dataset (in pretty much any format) of soil texture according to USDA classification (by U.S. Department of Agriculture). Is there anything that would cover the entirety of Europe?

I found the [Topsoil physical properties for Europe (based on LUCAS topsoil data)](http://esdac.jrc.ec.europa.eu/content/topsoil-physical-properties-europe-based-lucas-topsoil-data#tabs-0-description=1&tabs-0-description-2=) dataset from the European Soil Data Centre (ESDAC), which would suit my needs perfectly, except that it only covers the EU member countries and thus some countries are missing.

Comment: Am I missing something here? You want *European* data based on a *US* classification? Does the set you found meet that criterium?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the issue is that the data they've found doesn't have the coverage that they need. The information in it is what they're looking for though.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The [USDA classification](http://images.slideplayer.com/15/4740178/slides/slide_9.jpg) is widely used, as for the data I found, there is a link to [USDA Texture](http://esdac.jrc.ec.europa.eu/public_path/usda.png) which is perfect except for the missing non-EU countries.

Comment: http://www.iuss.org/index.php?article_id=174 may or may not be helpful.

Comment: A former colleague had the same problem (European soil data in US classification schema). As far as I know he ended up creating his own mapping from the available European data set schema to the US schema he needed. However, the mapping is ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lenghty unsuccessful search, I found an option to do my own mapping. There are [global datasets with the percentages of clay, silt and loam](http://globalchange.bnu.edu.cn/research/soilw) available from the Land-Atmosphere Interaction Research Group at Sun Yat-sen University and I used the [R soiltexture package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/soiltexture/soiltexture.pdf) for the classification. I ended up making a dataset covering my domain of interest in 2 km resolution. I attached my map and the original map mentioned in the question for comparison (some of the colours are a bit off, but they should more or less correspond to the same category in both images). If anyone is interested in this data, feel free to let me know. [image: Custom mapping]My custom mapping.

[image: Original dataset from the European Soil Data Centre (ESDAC)]Original dataset from the European Soil Data Centre (ESDAC)